# Correcting file numbers using bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed, rename, filenames

I have a bunch of file names in a folder like this:

```
test_07_ds.csv
test_08_ds.csv
test_09_ds.csv
test_10_ds.csv
...
```

I want to decrease the number of every file, so that these become:

```
test_01_ds.csv
test_02_ds.csv
test_03_ds.csv
test_04_ds.csv
...
```

Here's what I came up with:

```
for i in $1/*; do
    n=${i//[^0-9]/};
    n2=`expr $n - 6`;
    if [ $n2 -lt 10 ]; then
        n2="0"$n2;
    fi
    n3=`echo $i | sed -r "s/[0-9]+/$n2/"`
    echo $n3;
    cp $i "fix/$n3";
done;
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: if you have perl based rename command, try `rename -n 's/\d+/sprintf "%02d", $&-6/e' test_*` ... `-n` option is for dry run.. it might complain about already existing file in case of clash, but should work if `test_*` is automatically version sorted, given numbers are all two digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` for simplification:

```
for f in *.csv; do
   mv "$f" $(awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} {$2 = sprintf("%02d", $2-6)} 1' <<< "$f")
done
```

Comment: Ah, using `_` as an awk separator, nice!

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```
shopt -s extglob
for i in test_{07..10}_ds.csv; do
    IFS=_ read s m e <<<"$i";         # echo "Start=$s Middle=$m End=$e"
    n=${m#+(0)}                       # Remove leading zeros to
                                      # avoid interpretation as octal number.
    n=$((n-6))                        # Subtract 6.
    n=$(printf '%02d' "$n")           # Format `n` with a leading 0.
    # comment out the next echo to actually execute the copy.
    echo \
        cp "$i" "fix/${s}_${n}_${e}";
done;
```

Or collapsing it all together

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
for i in ${1:-.}/*; do                    # $1 will default to pwd `.`
    IFS=_ read s m e <<<"$i";             # echo "Start=$s Middle=$m End=$e"
    n=$(printf '%02d' "$((${m#+(0)}-6))")
    cp "$i" "fix/${s}_${n}_${e}";
done;
```

Comment: To force base 10 when a variable might start with a zero, you can also use `var=010; echo $(( 10#$var ))`. Note that the `$` inside `$(())` is required in this case.

Comment: @BenjaminW. True, and (almost) correct. Try: `a='0006 + 2*3<<6'; echo $((10#$a))`. Any true decimal integer should not contain `+`, `*` or `<`. Parsing integers is not so simple.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I should have added a `n=${m//[^0-9]}` as the first filter, but couldn't bring myself to explain all the detail of why that is actually needed.

Comment: Sure, it can't parse and clean an expression for you. I just meant it as an alternative to `${m#+(0)}`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yep, I understand. A `$((10#$a))` removes zeros (if that is the one problem to be solved), but it doesn't integrate well with other additional filters (if needed)., Once an arithmetic expansion is used, the processing of the variable ends. Filtering as text lends itself to additional cleaning steps. Thinking of that, I believe it should be the preferred way to clean the zeros in front of a variable value. That's why I used it here.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following code and  let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'FNR==1{OLD=FILENAME;split(FILENAME, A,"_");A[2]=A[2]-6;NEW=A[1]"_"A[2]"_"A[3];system("mv " OLD " " NEW);close(OLD)}' *.csv
```

Also I had assumed like your files are always starting from _7 name so I have deducted 6 from each of their names, also in case you could put complete path in mv command which is placed in above system awk's built-in utility and could move the files to another place too. Let me know how it goes then.

Comment: This is exactly what @anubhava is doing, +1 for effort though!